# How to stop Meteor.http.get() encoding Chinese character in the url

Tags: http, url, meteor, get, encode

I use Meteor.http.get() to get a user profile from an API in my Meteor application. Sometimes there will be Chinese characters in the url. For an example:

```
Meteor.http.get('https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/us/左手-1241/profile')
```

However, since the Meteor.http.get() method will encode Chinese character, the user profile cannot be found. For an example:

```
{ statusCode: 404,
     error: 'Found no user with the BattleTag: w%C2%BF%C3%94%C3-1241' } }
```

How can I stop Meteor.http.get() encoding Chinese character in the url so that something like the "%C2%BF" in url become normal Chinese character?

Comment: You can't have "normale chinese characters" in a valid URL. What's buggy seems to be the server.

Comment: Problem solved! The problem is really the server. It encoded the chinese characters wrongly.